# Pythonic Way To Replace Dict Keys and/or Values

Tags: python, dictionary, substitution

I'm looking for an 'efficient' way to iterate through a dictionary, and replace any key or value that starts with the term 'var'.

For example, if I have this:

```
data = {
    "user_id": "{{var_user_id}}",
    "name": "bob",
    "{{var_key_name}}": 4
}
```

and I have this dict of variable values:

```
variables = {
    "user_id": 10,
    "key_name": "orders_count"
}
```

Then I'd like my final data dict to look like this:

```
data = {
    "user_id": 10,
    "name": "bob",
    "orders_count": 4
}
```

Comment: There’s no particularly efficient way, you’ll have to iterate through all keys and values. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't get what the common link is between `data` and `variables`. There doesn't seem to be any identifier to match things up if there are multiple entries in the dicts. Presumably your real dicts don't look like this because there's nothing to iterate through here really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're treating it like a text template language (and if you are, then why not make it string.format(**variable) compatible syntax?) use text replacement:

```
import ast
import re

text = re.sub('{{var_(.*?)}}', lambda m: variables[m.groups()[0]], str(data))    
data2 = ast.literal_eval(text)

print(data2)
```

Comment: This works perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for. I just needed to make a slight modification to : `text = re.sub('{{var_(.*?)}}', lambda m: str(variables[m.groups()[0]]), str(data))` (wrapped the lambda in str()

Answer (score 1):

In straight-forward way:

```
result = {}
for k,v in data.items():
    if '{{var_' in k:     # if `{{var..}}` placeholder is in key
        result[variables[k[6:-2]]] = v
    elif '{{var_' in v:   # if `{{var..}}` placeholder is in value
        result[k] = variables[v[6:-2]]
    else:
        result[k] = v

print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'user_id': 10, 'orders_count': 4, 'name': 'bob'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty manual algorithm, but here goes:

```
for key, value in data.iteritems():
    if "var" in str(key):
        #iterate through "variables" to find the match
    elif "var" in str(value):
        #iterate through "variables" to find the match

    #populate "data" with the key value pair
```

This will work, but it's kind of messy if you can't *guarantee uniqueness*, especially in the case where a **key** needs to be replaced.