# Create and update dictionary with placeholder variables in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to achieve something like this

```
classroom = {"john" : {"grade_math": placeholder_grade_math,
                       "grade_physics": placeholder_grade_physics}
```

then

```
grades = {"placeholder_grade_math": str(10),
          "placeholder_grade_physics": str(8))
```

so now I would like to match the keys of `grades` to the placeholders of `classroom` and update it. Is there any pythonic way of doing this?

I have come across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718629/pythonic-way-to-replace-dict-keys-and-or-values) but i m trying to achieve the same thing without the regexp.

Edit:

I should point out that dict `classroom` works like a template. It is passed to a class as is. The placeholder variables, are produced in the execution and i want to update them without having to use the keys.

Of course the expected output is

```
classroom = {"john" : {"grade_math": "10",
                       "grade_physics": "8"}
```

but somehow "unpacked" from `grades` to `classroom`

Another edit:

Say now that the original `classroom` changes to

```
classroom = {"john" : {"grade_math": placeholder_grade_math,
                       "grade_physics": placeholder_grade_physics,
                       "grade_geometry": placeholder_grade_geometry}
```

but `grades` remains the same. The reason i m looking to sort of "unpack" is because i want to be able to modify the keys only in 1 place (the `classroom`) and the placeholder is filled without me having to fix the other part as well (`grades`).

Comment: It's not clear what your final output is. The following will do what you have stated, but I don't think it's what you want: `grades = classroom["john"]`

Comment: What is the output you'd expect here and what is `placeholder_grade_math`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a function:

```
def make_classroom(grades):
    return {
               "john": {
                           "grade_math": grades['math'],
                           "grade_physics": grades['physics']
                       }
           }

classroom = make_classroom({'math': "10", 'physics': "8"})
```

Comment: a prefered solution would be to not have `classroom` inside a function in order to update it.

Comment: You can't do what you want with an ordinary `dict`.

Comment: Can you suggest another structure then?

Comment: I would suggest not tying the contents of one container to the contents of another. If you want to update a classroom, update the classroom, not a separate container of grades.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
classroom = {"john" : {"grade_math": grades['placeholder_grade_math'],"grade_physics": grades['placeholder_grade_physics']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like that would work too:

```
def getStudentGrades(**kwargs):
  classroom = {"john" :
   {
    "grade_math": kwargs["placeholder_grade_math"],
    "grade_physics": kwargs["placeholder_grade_physics"],
    "grade_geometry": kwargs["placeholder_grade_geometry"]
   }
  } 

  return classroom

if __name__ == "__main__":

  kwargs = {
   "placeholder_grade_math": str(10),
   "placeholder_grade_physics": str(8),
   "placeholder_grade_geometry": None
  }
   ### you can change geometry grades from None to 
   ### whichever score you would like, using `None` for reference.
  getJohnsGrade = getStudentGrades(**kwargs)
  print(getJohnsGrade)
```

Comment: I would like to be able to do this without having to place `classroom` inside a function

Comment: well either way you want to return classroom, using kwargs['key'] to pass in the value through the instance of the `getStudentGrades`...